# Replace '(a)' with '@‘within a python string

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I am iterating through a list of email addresses and found that a number were entered incorrectly, i.e., (a) instead of @. So, I am trying to replace (a) with @. The best I got so far is:

```
x = 'asdf(a)asdf.com'
found = re.sub(r'\s(a)\s', '@', x.strip(), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(found)
```

However, this simply prints the original input:

```
asdf(a)asdf.com
```

I tried a number of regexes, but it won't work. Please help!

A note to all who suggested using the str.replace() method. Since (a) is part of string, I would have to read the entire document as a (list of) strings, and then iterate through it. I don't think this is an economical solution in terms of processing power used. Also, the questions specifically asked for a regex and not a string method. Thanks for taking the time to respond anyway!

Comment: is http://ideone.com/J9x23b good?

Comment: `\s` matches whitespace characters.

Comment: You need to escape the `(` and `)` as they're used for grouping.

Comment: ideone.com/J9x23b works perfectly - thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your pattern to:

```
re.sub(r'\(a\)', '@', x.strip(), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

But you shouldn't be spamming people in the first place ;)

Comment: Haha, okay. It looks like the kind of obfuscation used by people that are afraid of spammers. Manually entered, unvalidated data can be "fun" to work with.

Answer (score 9):

This seems simple enough to use [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```
>>> x = 'asdf(a)asdf.com'
>>> x.replace('(a)', '@')
'asdf@asdf.com'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the inbuilt `str.replace` method.

```
a = 'asd(a)bcd.com`
b = a.replace('(a)','@')
```

Answer (score 1):

*Python Code*

```
x = 'asdf(a)asdf.com'
found = re.sub(r'\(a\)', '@', x.strip(), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(found)
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/J9x23b)**